# update existing primary key by adding prefix as cust001, cust002 in laravel and phpmysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin, primary-key, laravel-5.5

I want to update my existing id of customer table from **1,2,3** to **cust0001, cust0002, cust0003**.
Also the type of it is initially int(10) that might be changed too.
All I have to do for both **phpMyadmin** and **Laravel**.

Comment: And what is the reason? Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: what happens when you past the thousand numeric part?

Comment: organizational demands, do let me know what are the complications if we do so, the cust001 will be auto increment still.

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT only works with integer types. So you answered your question about "complications" yourself. Solve your display issues in the view layer - not in the DB.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel got your point, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: `SMALLINT(4) ZEROFILL`